# At hive query, Null COUNT in one row

Tags: sql, hive, count, hql, hiveql

I need to help about hql (hive sql)

for example, I have hive table, and data save like

[image]

I need to count Null in each rows.

in example, answer is

```
1
2
3
3
5
```

I tried case when, and sum(if..), but tables have too many rows.
so I want to find query..

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyspark. But you have to see how its performing for your scenario.

I have added comments in each step to explain the logic.

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,isnan, when, count

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df =spark.sql("select * from mytable")

#get count of null in each column
df_cnt_null=df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

#create total column from count of null in each column
df_cnt_null['total'] = df_cnt_null['col1'] + df_cnt_null['col2']... 

#show total_count of nulls 
df_cnt_null.select('total').show()
```